# How to view the combat knowledge tips for the second time?

Tags: genshin-impact

Is there a way to view the hints on the world mechanics for the second time?
Let's say I've read a hint, but then forgot it and want to remind miself what exactly was written there. How to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [update preview of 1.1](https://genshin.mihoyo.com/en/news/detail/6419) posted by Mihoyo, a feature called the "Archive System" will be introduced to allow players to view past tutorial logs in addition to various other log entries for world materials and elements.

[image]

> The Tutorials Archive is your go-to place for useful tips about "Elemental Reactions", "Enemies", "System", and "Adventure". Look there for all the tutorials you have triggered during your travels.
> Use the search function to find the tips you need.